# How to close websocket-connection manually in Cowboy-server?

Tags: erlang, websocket, cowboy

How can I close a websocket connection manually (from server side) in Cowboy-server?  I would check login/password in callback-module in **init/3** and kick "wrong" users with some return  code.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to return {shutdown, Req, State} from your handler:

https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/master/src/cowboy_websocket_handler.erl

Comment: How can I return atom **wrong_password_or_username** as reason? In **State**-variable?